# NHibernate Linq DateTime in Where-Clause not supported?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, datetime, where-clause

I try to use the fallowing query to get all companies, which are created after a specific date:

```
return session.Query<Company>().Where(x => x.Created > value)
```

When I execute this, I always get a System.NotSupportedException. When I remove the Where(), it is working. 
I use NHibernate 3.0. Does Linq in NH3.0 not support such Where-clauses? How can I do this instead?

Comment: What are the types of `x.Created` and `value` and what is the value of `Kind` for each? Do Where clauses on any other fields work?

Comment: Is it a DateTime? of the Nullable<T> variety?

Comment: x.Created is of Type DateTime and value is also of Type DateTime. Other fields are also not working. Could it be because Company is a Class which inherits from another (Contact)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem:

I have also a Skip() and a Take() used. This two has to be after the Where().

Comment: oh dint realise u r the one who asked the question. i hv no clue why u hv added an answer that is nt one..

Comment: This was the solution (put the Skip() and Take() after the Where()). I have thought I write this as an answer because it solves my problem instead as a comment. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not NH3 supporting where with NH3 you should be using QueryOver and not Query. So it should be

```
return session.QueryOver<Company>().Where(right condn);
```

whats the type of created in your query and i may be able to help

You can have the skip and take too that is totally fine.